# Add or Remove response header based on the user authorization or request url

Tags: iis, response-headers

I need to add and remove response headers from the page based on the user authorization, for example if the current user in anonymous then the most secured headers must be implemented, but if the user is logged-in as an administrator (for example) his security headers should be less restricted as it will prevent certain functionality.

is there a way to do this in the IIS or using onpresendrequestheaders

Please advise and thank you

Comment: "onpresendrequestheaders", so you are using ASP.NET 4.x? Edit your question to include such critical information please. You need to write some C# code to take care of that on ASP.NET side.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the IIS outbound rule to rewrite the response header to blank:

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Set custom HTTP response header">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_var" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="\folder\filename$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value=""/>
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

if you want to use the PreSendRequestHeaders you could use the below code:

```
void OnPreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString().Contains("filename"))
        {
            Response.Headers.Remove("variablename");
        }
    }
```

Reference link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.presendrequestheaders?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. And is there a way to validate if the user is logged in or not?

Comment: @AJaz in my opinion checking the authorized user is not possible by using iis URL rewrite module because it executed before the authentication module.